# Highlight a zone on the PdfJS Canvas

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I have a `React JS` project (similar to [this sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/pdf-viewer-w7wpu) on Sandbox) in which I'm using `PDF JS` to display the `PDF` document. I am trying to add a transparent highlight to areas or zones on the document but not sure how to or if that is possible.
Please suggest any sample if I can refer or any guidance in this direction is much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add a transparent box as below. Note, for the time being I have hardcoded the page reference

```
  // add transparent highlight to the canvas
  const canvasWrapper = document.querySelector('.pdfViewer');
  const canvases = canvasWrapper.querySelectorAll('.page');
  for (let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('page1'); //hardcoded for testing
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)';
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 50, 0, 1)';
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(70, 220, 150, 40); // adjust coordinates as needed
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
```